# Apache folder permission error

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-httpd

I have a folder name `public` that I set up Apache to serve files out of, for some reason I was getting a 403 with the error message:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

My solution was to create another folder (`test`) alongside it and use that to serve files out of.

What I don't understand is why if the permissions, as far as I can tell are identical between the two folders, yet using the first folder gives me permission errors.

How can I diagnose this further?

`ls -l` gives:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 daniel daniel 4096 Apr 26 19:10 public
drwxrwxr-x 2 daniel daniel 4096 Apr 26 19:10 test
```

**Edit**

Contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/daniel/public/default/public/
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /home/daniel/public/default/log/error.log
    CustomLog /home/daniel/public/default/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have the following directive setup in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /home/daniel/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

From under `/home/daniel/public/default` running `ls -Zd public test` gives

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 daniel daniel ? 4096 Apr 28 13:44 public
drwxrwxr-x 2 daniel daniel ? 4096 Apr 28 13:44 test
```

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: What is inside `test/` and `public/` respectively? Have you enabled `DirectoryIndex` or is there an `index.html` on both (and if so, are the file permissions on it identical)?

Comment: You didn't tell us what system you are using, so please show us output of: `ls -Zd public test`

Comment: Not enough information, especially missing details of the system, your steps, documentation you followed, etc.

Comment: Please give us some of the key stanzas from your httpd.conf file. Also take a look at your error logs, often here: `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. I like to tail it like this: `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log` and then reload the URL that's causing issues. You should see a 200 if it's working, otherwise you'll see the 403 message.

Comment: @Gnouc `DocumentRoot` setup within `000-default.conf` is `/home/daniel/public/default/public`

Comment: @SamiLaine Both folders have an `index.html` file with identical permissions. `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` is enabled.

Comment: @ArturSzymczak OS is `Linux version 3.13.7-x86_64-linode38`. Apache is `Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)`. I've added output of `ls -Zd public test` as an edit.

Comment: @slm No error messages under `/var/log/error.log` or /home/daniel/public/default/log/error.log  with verbosity set to `LogLevel warn`. I do get `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 459 "-"` in the access log when trying to access anything served out of the public folder.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking the Apache error log (in **/var/log/apache/** on Debian/Ubuntu or **/var/log/httpd/** on RedHat and derivatives). The error log will give you a more verbose indication of what's wrong; where's it's a permissions error or something else.

Another thing to try is to try and stat the file you're trying to access with sudo, with Apache's user. Something along the lines of:

```
sudo -u apache2 stat /var/www/public/index.html
```

That's assuming your web root is in /var/www and that your Apache server runs as the apache2 user. The above command will confirm whether or not the Apache process is able to read the file in question (has sufficient filesystem permissions). If it's readable (you get stat output instead of Permission denied), then the issue most likely lies with the Apache server config itself, like @mdpc suggested.

Comment: Running `sudo -u www-data stat /home/daniel/public/default/public/index.html` worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your apache configuration files to see if there are any allow/deny directives inside some of the directories.